# Main Thread & current Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class SimpleThreading
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Thread t=new Thread();
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

After writing the statement **t.start()**  it should print the current thread as "Thread-0" which is by-default name given by JVM.But it prints again the Main. Can anyone clear my doubt where I am going wrong?? the output of above code is:
**Thread-0
Main
Main**

Comment: `t.start()` will start a *new* thread. It doesn't affect the thread that is running the `main()` method, i.e. the "Main" thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your code is running in main thread. If you want to print out the name of the running thread, you must put the print out login within the thread.

Try below:

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); } });
System.out.println(t.getName());
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
t.start();
//System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Comment: The result should like below. 1. t.getName() print 'Thread-0'. 2. Thread.currentThread().getName() print 'main' and 3. t.start() starts the thread and invokes run() method and print 'Thread-0'.     
Result: Thread-0 
main                                                                                                                                                  
Thread-0

Answer (score 2):

Your main method runs in the `Main` thread. Therefore, both println statement before an after `t.start()` print `Main`.

Your second thread does nothing, since you didn't pass any `Runnable` instance to the `Thread` constructor.

If you pass a `Runnable` instance to the `Thread` constructor, and the `run()` method of that `Runnable` will include `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());`, you'll see `Thread-0` printed.

For example, if you are using Java 8, you can replace

```
Thread t=new Thread();
```

with

```
Thread t=new Thread(()->{System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());});
```

or you can write the same logic in pre-Java 8 code :

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the comments for explanation:

```
class SimpleThreading
{
    public static void main(String... args) // main thread starts.
    {
        Thread t=new Thread(); // new thread object is created. (This is similar to any other java object). No thread created yet.
        System.out.println(t.getName()); // Prints the default name
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // This line is executed by main thread. hence prints main
        t.start(); // Now, thread is created in runnable state
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // This line is executed by main thread. hence prints main 
    }
}
```